# Regex issue (long string)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have RegExp condition is `/^([0-9]*\.?[0-9])*$/` to test string.
My string are first is `1.2.840.346991791506342.1482500253171661`(large string) & second is `1.2.3.201922311129.10038` (short string).

It successfully search as both strings are OK.

But when I add space at the last of second string short string it's showing invalid that is right conclusion.

But when I add space in first string it should display invalid string as per code but it gets hanged why it is showing hang?

RegExp limit is exhausted? What will be the solution?

You can check this in notepad+ for testing purpose `^([0-9]*\.?[0-9])*$` use this formula directly.

Comment: Did you just find a bug in some regexp implementations ? :D Because this looks like pretty much a bug to me

Answer (score 3):

The way you have written your regex, having nested quantifier is leading it to **[catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)** leading it to hang/timeout.

**[Catastrophic Backtracking Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NmeGKi/1)**

You need to simplify your regex to something like this,

```
^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)*$
```

Let me know if this regex preserves your pattern.

**[Regex Demo not running into timeout](https://regex101.com/r/DAD3dz/1)**

You should in general avoid over nesting quantifiers in your regex, and rather try writing them in a simpler manner as much as you can. Even for short string like `1.2.840.3469931313.313`, see how much steps your regex is taking,

**[135228 steps taken](https://regex101.com/r/NmeGKi/2)**

and if you increase your string length little bit, then it runs into timeout/catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Glad to know its working well for you now. And `?:` is used to turn a group into non-grouping pattern and it's a good idea to do that unless you really need that group and it does not change the logical meaning of regex. Also consider accepting any answer if it helped :)

Comment: Kumar ,if have same string as above but I want to remove space at front & back end of string ,what will be regex?

Comment: @VikramNarke: Your question is a bit not clear. The regex I have given in my answer will not allow any space already. But if you want to allow space(s) at the beginning of text and/or at the end of text, you can use this regex `^\s*[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)*\s*$`

Comment: If u add sapce in a string (start or end)1.2.345.3456.1223.1space space space .it should remove the space & result should be displayed as 1.2.345.3456.1223.1 without any space . Whatever space at start & end it should be removed

Comment: @VikramNarke: Ok, so you want to remove all the space if it is either at the beginning of text or end of text. You can use this regex `^\s*|\s*$` and replace it with empty string which will remove the unintended space as you want. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WqwMQr/1/)

Comment: Pushpesh:Thanks for your great help.

Comment: @VikramNarke: Glad to help :). Also, can you upvote and accept my answer if it helped solved your problem. That way you get +2 rep and will help others in locating it and trust the answer.

Comment: @@pushpesh above mentioned regex failed for .99 number .if we just give dot and number even if it is showing ok results

Comment: @VikramNarke: If you don't want regex to accept purely decimal numbers, you can change the quantifier from first `\d` from `*` to `+` and use this regex `^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*$` This won't accept a value like `.99` or `.1` and will need at least one digit before decimal and accept strings like `1.99` or `20.22`